# Laplace transform of a Cauchy's problem

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, cauchy-problem

I have to determine the Laplace transform of $u$, where $u$ is the solution to this Cauchy's problem
$$ u'(t) + \int_0^t e^{t-s} \left( \int_0^s u(r) ~ dr \right) ~ ds = 0, t > 0, u(0) = 1$$

$L[u](z) = ~? $

I know the the Laplace transform is $ \int_0^{+\infty} u(t)e^{-zt} \ dt$ but I can't determine the $u$ function. Can you please help me? :(

Comment: Take the transform on both sides, like you would in simple ODEs. You'll need formulae for the transform of an integral and shifts by exponentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{u}'\pars{t} + \int_{0}^{t}\expo{t - s}
> \bracks{\int_{0}^{s}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\,\dd r}\dd s = 0\,,\quad t > 0.
> \qquad\mrm{u}\pars{0} = 1}$.

---

\begin{align}
0 & =
\mrm{u}'\pars{t} + \expo{t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-s}\bracks{s < t}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\bracks{r < s}\dd r\,\dd s
\\[5mm] & =
\mrm{u}'\pars{t} + \expo{t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{u}\pars{r}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-s}\bracks{r < s < t}\dd s\,\dd r
\\[5mm] &=
\mrm{u}'\pars{t} + \expo{t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\bracks{r < t}
\pars{\expo{-r} - \expo{-t}}\,\dd r
\\[5mm] & =
\mrm{u}'\pars{t} + \expo{t}\int_{0}^{t}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\expo{-r}\,\dd r -
\int_{0}^{t}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\,\dd r
\end{align}

> Multiply both members by $\ds{\expo{-st}}$ and integrate over $\ds{t > 0}$
>   $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{note that}\ \hat{\mrm{f}}\pars{s} \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{t}\expo{-st}\,\dd t ~}}$:

\begin{align}
0 & =
-\ \overbrace{\mrm{u}\pars{0}}^{\ds{=\ 1}}\ + s\,\hat{\mrm{u}}\pars{s} +
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-st}\expo{t}\int_{0}^{t}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\expo{-r}
\,\dd r\,\dd t -
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-st}\int_{0}^{t}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\,\dd r\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-1 + s\,\hat{\mrm{u}}\pars{s} +
\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\expo{-r}
\int_{r}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{s - 1}t}\dd t\,\dd r - \int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\int_{r}^{\infty}\expo{-st}\dd t\,\dd r 
\\[5mm] & =
-1 + s\,\hat{\mrm{u}}\pars{s} + {1 \over s - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\expo{-sr}\dd r -
{1 \over s}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{u}\pars{r}\expo{-sr}\dd r
\\[5mm] & =
-1 + s\,\hat{\mrm{u}}\pars{s} + \pars{{1 \over s - 1} -
{1 \over s}}\hat{\mrm{u}}\pars{s} \implies
\bbx{\ds{\,\hat{\mrm{u}}\pars{s} = {s^{2} - s \over s^{3} - s^{2} + 1}}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{s^{3} - s^{2} + 1 = 0}$ has one negative real root
>   $\ds{s_{1} \approx -0.7549}$ and two complex roots
>   $\ds{a \pm b\ic\approx 0.8774 \pm 0.7449\ic}$.

---

With $\ds{c > a}$, $\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{t}}$ is given by:
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{t} & =
\int_{c - \infty\ic}^{c + \infty\ic}{s^{2} - s \over s^{3} - s^{2} + 1}\,
\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} =
{s_{1} - 1 \over 3s_{1} - 2}\,\expo{-\verts{s_{1}}t} +
2\,\Re\pars{{a + b\ic - 1 \over 3\bracks{a + b\ic} - 2}\,
\expo{\bracks{a + b\ic}t}}
\end{align}

Comment: Do you use $[s < t]$ as an Iverson bracket, returning $1$ is the bracketed condition is true?

Comment: In the end I prefered to use the convolution product, but this helped me a lot.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Yes. Iverson Bracket is quite fine. It lets easily keep tracks of several conditions. I guess it avoids to make mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio Thanks. There are a few ways to get the same result.

Comment: @FelixMarin I just wanted to be sure; I don't see it used much outside the text *Concrete Mathematics.*